# Polynomial Linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the problem:
$P_n$ is the space of polynomials less then or equal to $n$. The mapping $L: P_2 \longrightarrow P_3, \ 
L(p(t)) = (t+1)p(t+1)$, where $p(t_0)$ is the polynomial of degree less or equal to $2$.

1). Find the kernel of $L$.

2) Let $p_0 = 1, p_1 = t, p_2 = t^2$, be the basis in $P_2$. Find the matrix of the corresponding matrix transformation.

My question is how do I set this up into a matrix transformation.
I plugged $(t+1)p(t+1)$ into the following form and multiplied out using the form $P(t) = p_0 + p_1t + p_2t^2$, and got a set $(p_0 +2), (2p_1+3p_2)t, (p_1 + 3p_2)t^2, p_2t^3.$

I feel like maybe I shouldn't use $p$'s in my formula, that that may be confusing me. Is this a valid approach?

Answer (score 1):

0.) Yes, it's better to use another letter for the general coefficients, say, $p(t) =a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2$. 
Then $p(t+1)=a_0+a_1(t+1)+a_2(t+1)^2$.

1. If $p$ is in the kernel, that means $L(p)=0$, that is $(t+1)p(t+1)$ is the zero polinomial, so $p(t+1)=0$ and $p(t) =0$ follows.
2. Just put the coordinates w.r.t the standard basis $1,t,t^2, t^3$ of $L(1),\,L(t),\,L(t^2)$ into the columns of the matrix.